# Google Analytics to gather FPS from javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I've been reading about Google Analytics, using analytics.js. I successfully use it on a blog I've made using Jekyll. I made a javascript game that can successfully display the frames per second it runs on the screen.

In this javascript game, I want to use a timer so that, from time to time (each minute?), I would send the fps to Google Analytics. FPS is my first metric in Google Analytics. The code is something like this, according to the docs:

```
sendtoga = function(){
    ga('set', 'metric1', this.FPS.toString());
    this.gatimer = setTimeout("sendtoga()", 60000);
}
```

The variable `this.FPS` is updated every second with a new FPS value. I just want to have an idea if my code runs well at most platforms or if I still need to keep optimizing. Is there a more appropriate way to measure frames per second? Does GA will allow me to know in which browsers/devices it's performing better and which is performing worse?

Comment: Frames per second will also depend on the spec of the player's machine. Without those details your stats won't be that useful.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I know the `send,pageview`  allow me to view the devices used. I don't know if this is available when using `set,metric1`because I've never done this before...

Comment: How about the clock speed, graphics card, number of tabs open, number of other applications open, etc?

Comment: It's a 2d game, it's very simple, but I do see impact from resolution on the devices I have tested - it just works way better in smaller resolutions. My feeling is browser, browser version and resolutions has bigger impact on the performance. But I have a very small number of devices to test. If I could put online and just ask people to try it out, and get the stats automatically, it would be great!